# Talend (Ubuntu) - Read System Variables

Tags: talend

I wanted to create a flow which would pick a configuration file based on the system variable "WORK_ENV". I can't seem to do that in the Java node of my talend job.

However, if I do "echo $WORK_ENV" on the ubuntu terminal, I can see the following output.

[image]

Have tried using System.getenv("WORK_ENV") as well as the newer System.getProperty("WORK_ENV"). Both of them yield null.

Web search suggests me that the same constructs are working for people but for some odd reason, it isn't working for me.

The Talend Version is Open Studio 7.0.1, on Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
String work_env=(String)System.getenv("WORK_ENV");

System.out.println("Work Environment is " + work_env);
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use context parameters to pass that value down to your job.
You can declare a context variable in your job called `ENV`. When you build your job as a standalone you get a launcher for *nix systems which looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd `dirname $0`
ROOT_PATH=`pwd`
java -Xms64M -Xmx1024M -cp .:$ROOT_PATH:$ROOT_PATH/..other jars.. talend_project.talend_job_0_1.talendJob --context=Default "$@"
```

You can then send the environment variable to your job by doing:

```
talendJob_run.sh --context_param ENV=$WORK_ENV
```

in your Talend job you can then use `context.ENV`